# Replace Image/shape in visio c#

Tags: c#, replace, automation, visio

I am using the following code to drop an jpeg image onto Visio drawing page, but every time I run my application the image which I drop will be placed on top of  the earlier image that I had dropped . My question is how to replace the image/shape so that earlier image is replaced with the new image.
I tried using shpNew.ReplaceShape(imageFile, 0); but it is again overlapping onto the earlier image.

My another thought be to remove earlier shape and dropping the new image.
Please let me know for efficient approach.

```
private void DropImage(Visio.Page vPag, string imageFile)
    {
        if (vPag != null)
        {
            var shpNew = vPag.Import(imageFile);
            //Set position
            shpNew.CellsU["PinX"].FormulaU = "75mm";
            shpNew.CellsU["PinY"].FormulaU = "175mm";
            //Set size
            shpNew.CellsU["Width"].FormulaU = "100mm";
            shpNew.CellsU["Height"].FormulaU = "80mm";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ReplaceShape method works **ONLY** for shapes based on masters !!!

> ### Shape.ReplaceShape Method (Visio)
>
> Replaces the specified shape with an instance of the master passed as the 
>   first parameter, and returns the new shape.

But **NOT** for all visio shapes and foreign object such as inserted images
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229596.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for the information. If Replace method is not supported, may I know how to delete or remove the earlier image which I have inserted so as to drop the newer one like shpNew.delete of VBA in c#?

Comment: I always drop one image per page

Answer (score 0):

i find your previous thread: [Insert an Jpeg/bmp image onto the visio drawing using VBA/C#](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29016162/insert-an-Jpeg-bmp-image-onto-the-visio-drawing-using-VBA-C.html)

```js
Sub v()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim os As Shape
    Dim ns As Shape
    Dim x As Single, y As Single
    For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes
    ' find images
    If shp.Type = 4 Then
    ' define os variable as founded image
    Set os = shp
    End If
    Next
    If IsEmpty(os) Then
    MsgBox "Picture not found"
    Else
    ' define X and Y position
    x = os.Cells("PinX")
    y = os.Cells("Piny")
    ' insert new picture
    Set ns = ActivePage.Import("c:\Users\Surrogate\Desktop\ycnex.png")
    ' place new shape to old shape coordinates
    ns.Cells("pinx") = x
    ns.Cells("piny") = y
    ' delete old shape
    os.Delete
    End If
    End Sub
```